# pushwoosh Send Push - Additional data - custom data

Tags: android, ios, pushwoosh

Setting in custom data of my push:

```
{"tab":"question","url":"http://www.webyo.es"}
```

And on my Android I'm receiving:

```
{"u":"{\"tab\":\"question\",\"url\":\"http:\/\/www.webyo.es"}"}
```

The Json received is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you received is invalid, corrected JSON is ,

```
{
    "u" : {
        "tab" : "question",
        "url" : "http://www.webyo.es"
    }
}
```

minified java version,

```
String s="{\"u\":{\"tab\":\"question\",\"url\":\"http://www.webyo.es\"}}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you received JSON with last quote (") not escaped? This can't be true. This is what I receive:

"u":"{\"tab\":\"question\",\"url\":\"http://www.webyo.es\"}"

Please note "u" is a JSON String.